# how do i send javascript variables to PHP and return the results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a form with inputs (each with ID `param`,`param1`,`param3` respectively) and an external php file with a function called `getform()` that takes three parameters from the form (`param`, `param1`, `param3` respectively).

A text feild with id `results` to display the response from php file.
I have placed `onclick` function on `param3`.

I need whenever a user types something in `param3` it should be sent to php file and the results displayed in the text filed of id `results`.

here is my code

```
<script>
  function post(){
    var param = $('#param').val();
    var param2 = $('#param2').val();
    var param3 = $('#param3').val();
    $.post('curencyconvert.php', {
      postparam: param,
      postparam2: param2,
      postparam3:param3
    }, function(data){
      $('#results').html(data);
    });
  }
</script>
```

my php function in the  php file

```
function Conv($param,$param2,$param3){
    //my code here
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: `$_POST` is where you'll find your `postparam` and `postparam2` etc

Comment: the problem am not geting any respose form my php file. it seem like the javascript is not working. not even sending any thing. i have checked with javascrit alert(). but find no data sent to the php

Comment: You should try ajax, as described by @Faiz99 or even by @M A SIDDIQUI, In your case when did you call method Conv? It will not get called automatically

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_POST)){
//Calling the defined function here
Conv($_POST['postparam'], $_POST['postparam2'], $_POST['postparam3']);
}
```

Add these line below your function code.. and better echo the output in your function instead of returning it.

Comment: the problem am not geting any respose form my php file. it seem like the javascript is not working. not even sending any thing. i have checked with javascrit alert(). but find no data sent to the php

Comment: Where are calling the post  function...??

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#param3').change(function() {
// put here the code //
} );
})
```

Comment: you can use it to control the change of text in the #param3 , next you should add your code to put it in a hidden text box and submit the text box value to php file

Answer (score 0):

What errors you get in Console(firbug)?

As stated by other answers $_POST should be used.

What your php code returns if it returns an array or returns an object   It can not be put into the Input. Return value must be a
    string

PHP code must be :

```
      function Conv($param,$param2,$param3){
        //my code here
          // take particular field of the DB results or resultset that you want to show in the input.
            return $output['name'];

        }
```

I know answer is incomplete because your question is incomplete.
Please let me know errors from the console so that i can help you further

Answer (score 0):

echo instead of return.

```
if(isset($_POST)){
  echo Conv($_POST['postparam'], $_POST['postparam2'], $_POST['postparam3']);
}
```

Do something like this, it is more clean:

```
Conv($param, $param2, $param3){
   // your code here
   return $output;
}
```

As for the javascript part, jquery ajax is your friend

```
 function post(){

    var param = $('#param').val();
    var param2 = $('#param2').val();
    var param3 = $('#param3').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/path/to/file',
        type: 'POST',
        data : { postparam: param, postparam2: param2, postparam3: param3 },     
    }).done(function(data) {
          $('#results').html(data);
    });

}
```